# Google position volatility (Webmaster Tools)

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, seo-audit

ok guys, so i guess this question might also be abouth Google math.
so my webpage is new (redesigned) and my SEO is quite better than the one i had. i am tracking on WMT how new site behaves on Google and for Keywords i think they are relevant, they are striking firstpage positions (i checked theem myself on google search) eventhough WMT gives me Average Postion like 30...28...23, but keeps rising.
one day i look up WMT and webpage drops  from 23 to 58, all of the sudden (and im like pissed off because i want it only to rise). but also i see some new keywords on the list for the same page which rank 150 or 412 place.

1. did my overall rank drop because of those new keywords/queries?
2. does that drop affect keywords/queries ranking which i think they`re relevant for bringing traffic to my webpage?
3. does the rising number of impressions and new keywords/queries affect ranking to drop in terms of "impressions rise with new low ranked keywords/queries so average page ranking declines on WMT"?
4. how relevant is the WMT Average ranking and impressions statistic if i see my page on search engine being on the first page for keywords/queries i want it to be ranked with?

i would appreaciate any extra hints related to this matter. thx a lot.

Comment: Search is not about keywords and has not been since around 1998. Thinking in terms of keywords is a misnomer. There are plenty of search queries that will find your content. It is about matching search intent with content. With that, having your content found via many search queries is what you want. Focusing on a narrow list of keywords is to severely limit your search potential. Also, please do not associate rank with keywords. Rank is based upon a sites performance including votes via links. Cheers!!

Comment: it was a misnomer, no doubt... but you seem to be a bit too heated up  about it... which doesnt make you wrong. thx

Comment: It does drive me nuts that all the SEOs talk so much about keywords when search is about whole language and search is constantly moving through the cosmos and does not stand still. Since Google, search has been about semantics and not keyword matches. The more that a price if content finds a reader the better. This means that content should be more attractive than just  few words. Heated? No. Eager? Definitely. A bit of Don Quixote? Perhaps. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

Firstly Google Webmaster Tool gives you an estimate and it changes over time but its good place to monitor, it may not reflect live ranking.

Generally, your actual position may be better than Webmaster position.

With regards to drop in ranking is concerned, it may have happened due to several factors.

The following activities may help:

- Make sure your website got unique and well-targeted content.
- Generally, ranking drop is also caused by the kind of link building strategy you may have. Make sure you got good quality links, avoid any poor links.
- Lastly, build authority for your website by having G+, Google Local Listing, YouTube, and links coming from leading social sites.

Comment: thx TopQnA. since you mentioned quality of links here, which is the method/software you check quality of your links?

Comment: As you may know, to get better ranking you need to have good quality content on your website and quality backlinks. Now, to answer your question, there is no specific software which can check quality vs poor links. Either you need to learn about SEO process which will help you identify quality vs poor links. Alternatively, you seek help from SEO experts you may know. You can also learn if you will spend some time about how to do quality backlinks.